# The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. Node.js azure

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops

I have node.js application it works locally when I deployed it to Azure App service I get bellow error:

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

bellow is my server.js code:

```js
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const errorhandler = require("errorhandler");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const router_1 = require("./routes/router");
const bunyan_logger_1 = require("./lib/loggers/bunyan.logger");
require("reflect-metadata");
//const database = require('./data/dbprovider/dbmssql');
class Server {
    constructor() {
        this.port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
        this.logger = new bunyan_logger_1.bunyanLogger();
        this.app = express();
        this.initExpressMiddleWare();
        this.initCustomMiddleware();
        this.initRoutes();
        this.start();
    }
    start() {
        this.app.listen(this.port, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                this.logger.StartLogger().error('In Server.TS start see details: ' + err);
            }
            else {
                console.log('Listening on http://localhost:%d', process.env.NODE_ENV, this.port);
            }
        });
    }
    initExpressMiddleWare() {
        this.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
        this.app.use(morgan('dev'));
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
        this.app.use(errorhandler());
        this.app.use(cookieParser());
        this.app.use(cors());
        // Add headers
        this.app.use(function (req, res, next) {
            // Website you wish to allow to connect
            const allowOrigin = ['https://senserver4.azurewebsites.net','http://localhost:3000'];
            const origin = req.headers.origin;
            if (allowOrigin.indexOf(origin) > -1) {
                res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
            }
            // Request methods you wish to allow
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
            // Request headers you wish to allow
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
            // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
            // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
            // Pass to next layer of middleware
            next();
        });
        //this.app.use(csrf({ cookie: true }));
        // this.app.use((req: { csrfToken: () => void; }, res: { locals: { _csrf: any; }; cookie: (arg0: string, arg1: any) => void; }, next: () => void) => {
        //     let csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
        //     res.locals._csrf = csrfToken;
        //     res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', csrfToken);
        //     next();
        // });
        process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
            if (err)
                console.log(err, err.stack);
        });
    }
    initCustomMiddleware() {
        if (process.platform === "win32") {
            require("readline").createInterface({
                input: process.stdin,
                output: process.stdout
            }).on("SIGINT", () => {
                process.exit(1);
            });
        }
        process.on('SIGINT', () => {
            process.exit(1);
        });
    }
    initRoutes() {
        (new router_1.Router()).load(this.app, './controllers');
    }
}
let server = new Server();
//# sourceMappingURL=server.js.map
```

I have created web.config file in root of my project below is the web.config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
<appSettings>

</appSettings>
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>

<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />

<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;routes\*.js;views\*.pug"/>

<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />

</handlers>

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <remove segment="bin" />
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>

<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />

    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I have added my server.js in path mapping, but I could not resolve the issue.

Error I get in console:

```
Tue Jan 14 2020 16:01:06 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
D:\home\site\wwwroot\public\data\repos\Agent.repo.js:13
async getAllAgent() {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\public\controllers\api\agents\agent.controller.js:3:22)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

Comment: You need to find the server error in the server log, and edit it into your question.

Comment: You can visit https://<webappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net to check if the app is correctly deployed to Kudu server. If not. you need to check if your pipeline deployment task is correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

This error is the common description of IIS server 500 error. It will be hard to find the root cause of the question by only the general description.

Please try below code of web.config to show the details that might helps you and don't comment your previous code.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```