# Node Express Webpack API Release to Azure Dev Ops

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to release my project using Nodejs Express on Azure Dev Ops and Deploy on Release, but when I try to open the link. I'm getting a "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred." error.

YAML:
pool:
name: Azure Pipelines
steps:

- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 14.x'
  inputs:
  versionSpec: 14.x
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm install'
  inputs:
  verbose: false
- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'npm custom'
  inputs:
  command: custom
  verbose: false
  customCommand: 'run build'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
  PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

Package Script
[image: Package Script]

Webpack.config
[image: Webpack.config]

and on Azure Pipeline
[image: Azure Pipeline]
the default setting of npm install and build

and on Azure Release
[image: Realease]

All are working fine, on the build and release.

### Blank Page
[image: blank]

I'm starting to guess the problem was from the azure portal, or on the way it was setup. Because I didn't create the portal. I'm only the Contributor.

Please help clarify this.

I try to build all files on SCM \wwwroot

[image: wwwroot]

Comment: which operating system are you using Linux or windows ?

Comment: once please checked the version which you are using in azure -webapps and the version which in your local system are same.

Comment: Goto azure app -> click on `configurations` ->create `new application settings` -> then use the `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` and save the settings. after that try to redeploy the application.

Comment: 1.) I'm using windows.
2.) What do you mean by the version, the nodejs? 
3.) I'll try to add SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT, then redeploy it

Comment: SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT added, after redeploy, it still the same error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Comment: I've check the Version on my Local Node was V14.0.0, while on azure portal Node~18, I also the checked the scm wwwroot which is v14.20.0, on Azure Configuration my WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION was set to ~14

Comment: I have deployed the app service from visual studio code and it's working fine. would you like to follow those steps?

Comment: I'll try but my Owner keep emphasizing to release using the DevOps. Don't know why.

Comment: I got an error of "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.", but was deployed successfully

Comment: Do I need to add something on the Azure Portal?

Comment: please follow this [Link](https://blog.restcase.com/deploying-node-or-azure-webapp-from-vsts-release-pipeline-2/) it might help you.

Comment: ok, I'll try to create a new project, maybe there's something wrong with my code

Comment: I've tried a new project and deploy on vscode, its working now

Comment: glad to hear. that the given suggestion had worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make sure the index.js file is deployed to your azure app service
- As you have some issues with your existing application Create the new application using this [MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops&pivots=pipelines-yaml)
- Sign into Azure Pipelines. Your browser will go to to display your Azure DevOps dashboard.
- Create New pipeline under the pipeline's menu of your project
- Select GitHub as the source code location.
- If the code is placed in GitHub, then login with Git Creds
- When the list of repositories appears, select your sample Node.js repository.
- Azure Pipelines analyzes the code in your repository and automatically gives a Node.js template for your pipeline. Select this template.
- Azure Pipelines will automatically generates a YAML file in your pipeline. Click on Save and Run > Commit Directly to Master Branch and then choose Save ad Run again.

A new run begins. Wait for the run to complete.

- The link is used to create a pipeline is azure devops  [Deploying a Node JS App to Azure App Service using Azure Dev-ops (Part 1)](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/deploying-node-js-app-using-azure-devops-part1-74cb13a6bd02)
- The link will be used to deploy the Nodejs app to Azure portal using azure pipelines [Deploying a Node JS App to Azure App Service using Azure Dev-ops (Part 2)](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/deploying-node-js-app-using-azure-devops-part2-4567e4cf783b)
- This error is a common description of the IIS server error 500. It will be difficult to find the root cause of the question with just a general description.
- For more details, please Reference the [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59691943/the-page-cannot-be-displayed-because-an-internal-server-error-has-occurred-node)